# TypeORM: How to add a constructor to a custom repository?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm working on upgrading TypeORM from version 2 to 3.

With the old way of creating a custom repository, I could do something like:

```js
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  async findUser() {
    ...
  }
}
```

With the new syntax, I have something like:

```js
export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
  constructor() {
    ...
  },

  async findUser() {
    ...
  },
}
```

The problem is that with this new syntax, having a constructor causes an error:

`AssertionError: repositoryConstructor is not a constructor`

How can I include a constructor or constructor-like functionality and avoid this error?